# C#: Entity Framework 6.2 for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm going to develop a Rest API in ASP.NET MVC.

I don't know how can I check which version of Entity Framework is available on VS2019 IDE for ASP.NET MVC application. How can I check it?

Besides, is it possible to use EF6.2 for MVC applications or it only belongs to ASP.NET Core?

Comment: There is MVC options both for .net framework and .net core and EntityFramework 6.3 is also ported to .net core as well. So you can pick either platform to develop with.

Comment: Current tendention is to use .Net Core. Use it, if there is no specific condition.

Comment: You can use EFCore 2.2 and EF6.3 in .NET framework, maybe even EFCore3.1 but not announced yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use EF6.2, because I am using that on my MVC project right now. as for the first question, you can try adding a nuget package while running a project in VS 2019 and see the EF versions available, although I think it is also the same with 2017.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use EF6.2 for MVC applications.